# rails assets:precompile during slug for s3 error: Fog provider and directory can't be blank when env are set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, assets

I decided to serve rails assets via S3; heroku has great tutorials on how to do this.  The site is now serving assets from my amazon bucket but I'm unsure why I had to manually run `heroku run rake assets:precompile` after a `git push heroku master` which runs a `rake assets:precompile`.

After running the `git push heroku master` the assets where not in my bucket and the output for the precompile stuff was:

```
AssetSync: using default configuration from built-in initializer
       AssetSync: using default configuration from built-in initializer
       rake aborted!
       Fog provider can't be blank, Fog directory can't be blank
       /tmp/build_3vtwfg15g8ajx/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/asset_sync-0.5.0/lib/asset_sync/asset_sync.rb:29:in `sync'
       /tmp/build_3vtwfg15g8ajx/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/asset_sync-0.5.0/lib/tasks/asset_sync.rake:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:nondigest
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
       Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
```

I did set the fog provider and directory with: `heroku config:add FOG_DIRECTORY=XXX FOD_PROVIDER=AWS` and calling heroku config --app  confirms this...so I don't get those errors.

The assets didn't show up in my bucket so I ran: `heroku run rake assets:precompile` and everything worked with a warning:

```
AssetSync: using default configuration from built-in initializer
AssetSync: Syncing.
[WARNING] fog: the specified s3 bucket name(ss_assets) is not a valid dns name, which will negatively impact performance.  For details see: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Bucket
Restrictions.html
```

Will I always have to run the precompile task after and just be okay with the push failure?  I'll check to see if the Warning of the directory name is causing the blank FOG errors on push

**EDIT**
Again asset_sync doesn't appear to have ENV variables when called in the assets:precompile task of the heroku push.  Running that task after push works but it 'annoying'.

Still not working for me, latest attempt was (per [asset_sync github project](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync/issues/41)):

lib/tasks/asset_sync.rake.

```
Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].enhance do
  AssetSync.sync
end

Rake::Task["assets:precompile:nondigest"].enhance do
  AssetSync.sync
end
```

I also attempted adding lines to my production.rb file such as:

```
  config.asset_sync.aws_bucket = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']
  config.asset_sync.fog_provider = ENV['FOG_PROVIDER']
```

Didn't work for me either.

Comment: This seems suspiciously similar to the problem in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755311/stop-assets-from-being-precompiled-locally-for-local-production-testing-of-a-her).

Comment: NO, this is a precompile error during heroku push.  The other is a local configuration to control where assets are precompiled.  The answer to this question will not answer the other and vice versa

Answer (score 10, accepted):

run below from [asset_sync docs Labs section](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync)

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
```

Hasn't made it's way into the platform as standard yet!

Comment: This is now completely out of date. Heroku returns this: No such feature: user-env-compile