# Stop assets from being precompiled locally for local production testing of a heroku rails asset_sync s3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, assets, production-environment

This app is deployed on heroku and uses asset_sync gem with s3 to serve assets.  I want to run my rails server in production locally to test out things before deployment to heroku.  When I run `rake assets:precompile` My local machine uploads files to my s3 bucket (all works fine) but I also notice assets are precompiled in my local public folder.

Precompiling on S3 and locally seems redundant, sometimes I want the assets precompiled to just S3, other times I may want to run a local production server with assets from my public directory and not bother uploading / referencing S3.

So how would I configure my machine to stop assets from being precompiled locally?

I'm open to any ways to configure my system.  Right now

I added several variables to my .bash_profile to store my AWS credentials.

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyy
export S3_BUCKET_NAME=my_bucket_name
export FOG_PROVIDER=AWS
export FOG_DIRECTORY=my_bucket_name
```

I've tried a rails environment/production.rb entry:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Thanks

Comment: This seems suspiciously similar to the problem in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750690/rails-assetsprecompile-during-slug-for-s3-error-fog-provider-and-directory-can).

Comment: No, this is a local configuration preference, the other question is an error during a heroku precompile push.  The answer for this will not answer that and visa versa.

Comment: Have you solved this? I am having the same issue. I'm considering amending the assets:precompile rake task to just do AssetSync.sync