# Fog provider can't be blank - fog-aws-asset_sync

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, cdn, fog

Ugh, I'm getting the same error as here....[rails assets:precompile during slug for s3 error: Fog provider and directory can't be blank when env are set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750690/rails-assetsprecompile-during-slug-for-s3-error-fog-provider-and-directory-can) on the solution is not working...

When I try to precompile assets, I get the following error:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
AssetSync: using default configuration from built-in initializer
AssetSync: using default configuration from built-in initializer
rake aborted!
Fog provider can't be blank
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/asset_sync-0.5.4/lib/asset_sync/asset_sync.rb:32:in `sync'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/asset_sync-0.5.4/lib/tasks/asset_sync.rake:3:in `block in
```

When I type heroku labs:list ... it shows that user-env-compile is enabled

```
[+] user-env-compile       Add user config vars to the environment during slug compilation
```

When I type heroku config...I can see that the fog variables are setup

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:            myid
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:        mykey
FOG_DIRECTORY:                mydirectory
FOG_PROVIDER:                 AWS
```

Why does it precompile some of the files, but then give the error?

Answer (score 4):

You're running this on your local machine?
You don't have access to Heroku's environment variables from your local machine.

You should either add the variables to your bash_profile, or try something like [direnv](https://github.com/zimbatm/direnv). If you're developing with [pow](http://pow.cx), your best option is [.powenv](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.2)

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="myid"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="mykey"
export FOG_DIRECTORY="mydirectory"
export FOG_PROVIDER="AWS"
```

Comment: Yup. this fixes it. Although I consider it to be a nasty hacky fix, because it violates DRY

Comment: Not necessarily. If you're running on a local machine, you're probably in development, which would warrant a separate S3 bucket, and different configuration.

I admit it is duplication if you want to access production assets in development, but whatever. It's a couple lines of configuration code to keep you from getting 1337hax'd.

Comment: Yeah, after further review... I agree, it's not so bad. You certainly don't want that stuff in your config files in GitHub or whatever. Also, it works OK, and since I've found the whole setup with rails development and Heroku a bit wobbly, that's a good thing.
 Although I do know for sure that some day I'll change the AWS or FOG parameters in one place and forget the other, and then nothing will work, and it'll take me 6 hours to figure this stuff out again :)